# Set Max. Size,Max Integer number and Max string length

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In my project I have textboxes where I will input data , like Name , Age , etc..

1. For the Name text I want to make it accept certain amount of str.
2. Age text box accept only till 3 int and max of a certain number
   where I can't add more to it.

Comment: Try it yourself first.

Comment: Also, when asking a question, it would help to mention which technology you're actually using. HTML based, WinForms, WPF, WinRT, etc., etc.

Comment: How do you define string length? UTF-16 code units? UTF-8 code units? Unicode code points? Number of rendered symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , You should try it yourself , but here is a little hints  : 
this bunch of code to make the text accept only letters no numbers , no spaces
Go to Text Name properties , from events Double click on KeyPress and try this :

```
 private void TxtName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
            e.Handled = true;

    }
```

This to set a maximum size of letters written , from the text name properties , go to events and double click on KeyDown and try this :

```
    private void TxtName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = TxtName.Text.Length;
            if(!(e.KeyData == Keys.Back && e.KeyData == Keys.Delete))
                try
                {
                    if (TxtName.Text.Length >= 20)
                    {
                        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
                catch { } 
}
```

This code to set a max. integer value , go to TextAge properties , from events Double click on Leave and try this :

```
    private void TxtAge_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myString = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        int i = Convert.ToInt16(myString);
        if (i > 150)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Age");
                TxtAge.Clear();
            (sender as TextBox).Focus();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MaxLength` property of the `TextBox` control - which you can set in code directly, or configure from the properties window in the VS designer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MaxLength` property of the TextBox control

You can use [validation controls](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp)

Example: For, age set the MaxLength property to 3

Answer (score 0):

'For Age TextBox Write This into Keypress Event

```
Public Sub TextBox1_Keypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Dim maxlen as Integer = 2 'Maximum Number Allowed


    Dim key = (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar))

        If key = 9 Or key = 8 Or (key >= 48 And key <= 57) Then
        Else
            e.Handled = True
            Beep()
        End If

    If sender.TextLength >= maxlen And key <> 8 And key <> 9 Then
        e.Handled = True
        Beep()
    End If
End Sub
```

'For Text

```
 Public Sub TextBox2_Keypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    Dim key = (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar))

    Dim maxlen as Integer = 10 'Maximum Allowed Text

    If sender.TextLength > maxlen Then
        e.Handled = True
        If key = 8 Then
            e.Handled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```